# Speed up repetitive completion of email

Tags: email, attachments

I want to send email with the same subject line, body text and pdf attachment to any one who asks me for the .pdf. I want to be able to use a keyboard short cut or similar to avoid having to type the same stuff every time.

Comment: You should add way more detail to your question for anybody to be able to come up with serious suggestions. What context are you talking about? What platform?

Comment: What email program do you use?

Answer (score 1):

`mailx` will allow you to send it out easily enough. Just throw together a small shell script that takes the address you're sending it to.

Answer (score 1):

In many email applications, you can create "template" messages that are mostly (or completely) prepared in advance, for exactly this purpose.

For example, in Microsoft Outlook, you can save an unsent email to a file as an Outlook message (.msg extension). Opening that file will reload the message, ready to send.

Mozilla Thunderbird has a similar feature as well.

I'd suggest creating just such a template message with the subject line in place, body already written and the PDF already attached. Sending it then becomes just a couple of keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Outlook, create the message (including the attachment), save it somewhere handy as a msg file, then when you want to send it simply double click the msg file, populate the To field, and hit Send.